# React 18 useState Callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that useState updates its states asynchronously, meaning that it does not wait for the state to be updated before running the next line of code. If I want to use the value of the state immediately after updating, I would have to use useEffect() with the state as the dependency. However, I'm facing an issue where useEffect() is rendering twice and I can't have that as this is a betting game. The user would pretty much win/lose money onload. I also read that this only happens during production and I have no way to verify this as I'm still building the game locally on my device. Here's my code :

```
const [ betMultiplier, setBetMultiplier ] = useState(1);

   const runMultiplier = () => {
    let layer = Math.random();
    let i = 0;

    if ( layer < 0.505 ) {
      setBetMultiplier( +(Math.random()*1+1).toFixed(2) )
    } else {
        while (layer > 0.5) {
          layer = Math.random()
          if (layer < 0.5) break
          i++
          if ( i > 17 ){
            setBetMultiplier(1000000)
            break;
          }
        }
        setBetMultiplier( +((Math.random()*(multiplierRange[i][1]-multiplierRange[i][0]))+multiplierRange[i][0]).toFixed(2) )
      }
    }
  } 

useEffect(()=> {
   if (multiplier >= betMultiplier) {
      console.log('you win!')
    } else {
      console.log('you lose!')
    }
},[betMultiplier])
```

since useState is set to (1) on default, when the page initially loads, the console logs "you win!" twice. FYI, multiplier is initially set to "2". I tried to stop useEffect from rendering on the initial load by using useRef [as shown in this blog](https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-prevent-useeffect-from-running-on-mount-in-react/), but it still runs the second time. I could bypass this by adding another "isMount" but that just seems like bad programming practice to me.

Comment: Can you set the initial value of the of the useState to be null and in your useEffect, only run your if statement if betMultiplier is not null?

Comment: @GustavVingtoft Hey Gustav! Amazing idea, That fixes the bug but I need an initial betMultiplier value so the game displays an initial value. Putting it as null makes the value go missing.

Comment: Why are you using an effect here? Depending on what you're doing, a Memo might work, but when you set state, the component will render, so you can use the derived state for things without effects and whatnot. For example, just put the code that you have in the effect right inline with no effect and see what happens.

Comment: A memo could work, but keep in mind, that memos are expensive, and should be used with some consideration. 

@rt10 if you don't want the game to be executed on load, how is the start of the game triggered? By a button mouseclick? 

Your comment is kind of contradicting. You don't want the game to run on init but you want to set the betMultiplier on init? Why is that important?

Comment: @GustavVingtoft the game is only played when the user clicks on a button. On init, it only renders the interface of the game. Similar to how slot machines work, the game loads but is only played when they click on the "play" button. The useEffect here is to process the winnings/loss depending on the outcome of the game. betMultiplier is initially set on init as it's to display the default value to the user, so they understand how the game works from the getgo. It's more of a UX thing.

Also, what do you mean by memos are expensive?

Comment: @rt10 The reason for asking is, I think you can solve the UX by some other way and then get my solution to work. Instead of the multiplier useState being your conditional render in the JSX code (I presume since you haven't posted that part of your component), maybe add another useState that will handle the conditional render of your game, so the useEffect subscribing to your multiplier useState isn't triggered onInit

Comment: @GustavVingtoft Thanks for the input, I actually didn't consider that and that's definitely doable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your original business logic, you could use this solution, in order not to run your useEffect onInit:

```
// OUTSIDE component
import {useEffect} from "react";

let isInitial = true;

export const YourComponent = () => {
    const [betMultiplier, setBetMultiplier] = useState(1);

    const runMultiplier = () => {
        let layer = Math.random();
        let i = 0;

        if (layer < 0.505) {
            setBetMultiplier(+(Math.random() * 1 + 1).toFixed(2))
        } else {
            while (layer > 0.5) {
                layer = Math.random()
                if (layer < 0.5) break
                i++
                if (i > 17) {
                    setBetMultiplier(1000000)
                    break;
                }
            }
            setBetMultiplier(+((Math.random() * (multiplierRange[i][1] - multiplierRange[i][0])) + multiplierRange[i][0]).toFixed(2))
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {

        if (isInitial) {
            isInitial = false;
            return;
        }

        if (multiplier >= betMultiplier) {
            console.log('you win!')
        } else {
            console.log('you lose!')
        }

    }, [betMultiplier]);


    return (
        <>JSX goes here</>
    )
}
```

Because the "isInitial" is outside of your component, it will only be initizialed once your file are loaded into the DOM and therefore will not change its state, if/when your component rerenders.